# str.replace() in a object

Tags: javascript, json

For my project i am pulling back data from a JSON file into a array, i am then looping through the data for each matching parameter that the user has entered. I want to replace a part of the string with an image where each object contains a certain letter.
Example : `{6} {w} {w}`
I want to replace each letter with a image that the letter represents?
I tried `$("#array").str.replace("{w}", "../images/wImage.png");`
Thanks any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: can you share what your input array and output array looks like?

Comment: Input array -     "cost": "{6}{W}{W}",
        "name": "Test",
        "number": "2"
I am not outputting an array, i am appending to a <p> tag

Comment: It is not an array, it is an object. Please update your question with these details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want this

```js
var images = document.querySelectorAll('.content img');
if (images) {
  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var element = images[i];
    switch (element.dataset.src) {
      case '{w}':
        element.src = 'http://www.img.gem-flash.com/images/18592592472630941439.jpg';
        break;
      case '{6}':
        element.src = 'https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGsQElcTdvKt0Bu1JsgDiRKKgqlqzfUOONBMl3TqTl3mjmgTO1';
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img src="" data-src='{6}' alt="">
  <img src="" data-src='{w}' alt="">
  <img src="" data-src='{w}' alt="">
</div>
```